# What is the proper way of using `group by` to get the desired results?

Tags: mysql, group-by

This is the structure of the table I'm querying:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| UserId  | ExperimentId | TaskId | TaskName | Errors | FileKey  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 12      | 10           | 8      | Jumping   | 9      | 1200298 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 12      | 10           | 8      | Jumping   | 7      | 1200297 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 12      | 10           | 8      | Jumping   | 6      | 1200296 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 12      | 10           | 8      | Jumping   | 8      | 1200295 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 12      | 10           | 6      | Writing   | 9      | 1200294 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 12      | 10           | 6      | Writing   | 2      | 1200293 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 12      | 10           | 6      | Writing   | 0      | 1200292 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 12      | 10           | 8      | Pointing  | 9      | 1200291 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 12      | 10           | 8      | Pointing  | 8      | 1200290 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 12      | 10           | 8      | Pointing  | 7      | 1200289 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The query that I'm using:

```
select
    UserId,
    TaskName,
    sum(Errors) as Errors
from
    UserTaskStats
where
    TaskName = TaskName
and
    UserId = UserId
group by
    Errors, TaskName
order by
    UserId asc;
```

An example of the results I get (ignore accuracy of values in `Errors` column):

```
--------------------------------
| UserId  | TaskName  | Errors |
--------------------------------
| 12      | Jumping   | 3      |
--------------------------------
| 12      | Jumping   | 3      |
--------------------------------
| 12      | Writing   | 8      |
--------------------------------
| 12      | Jumping   | 8      |
--------------------------------
| 12      | Writing   | 6      |
--------------------------------
| 12      | Writing   | 6      |
--------------------------------
| 12      | Pointing  | 6      |
--------------------------------
| 12      | Pointing  | 8      |
--------------------------------
| 12      | Jumping   | 8      |
--------------------------------
| 12      | Writing   | 8      |
--------------------------------
```

The result I want:

```
---------------------------------
| UserId  | TaskName  | Errors  |
--------------------------------
| 12      | Jumping   | 30      |
--------------------------------
| 12      | Writing   | 11      |
--------------------------------
| 12      | Pointing  | 24      |
---------------------------------
```

Am I not using `group by` properly? Is there another way to get the desired result?

Comment: What is the thinking behind `where TaskName = TaskName and UserId = UserId`? It is the same as `where TaskName IS NOT NULL and UserId  IS NOT NULL`. I've just removed it entirely from my answer for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close.

You desire a row for each `UserId, TaskName` group so just need to `group by UserId, TaskName`

```
SELECT UserId,
       TaskName,
       sum(Errors) AS Errors
FROM   UserTaskStats
GROUP  BY UserId,
          TaskName
ORDER  BY UserId ASC;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b6a5/1)

Comment: Do you really need the `WHERE` clause in this case?

Comment: @AshwinMukhija - No. I copied and pasted the OP query to start with. Apparently redundant `WHERE` now removed!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of doing it

```
select
  user_id,
  task_name,
  sum(errors)
from test
group by user_id , task_name
```

### Demo

Comment: `user_id` is not grouped by or aggregated so it will just return an undefined `user_id`

Comment: and this is what you haven't mentioned in your question. According to your question it is OK. You can add a group by user id and give more detail if you need something else

Comment: Also grouping by only task_name ignores the user_id and sums all the errors into one group.  So you'll get the `Pointing` with `348993` errors.

Comment: I guess I should have also mentioned that there are more than one `user_id`.

Comment: if you need the desired output for different user ids than post the output